# How do I skip to a certain part of my code if I encounter an error in Julia

Tags: if-statement, try-catch, julia

I have a 'wrapper function' that takes inputs and just runs a lot of functions in turn and spits out a result at the end. A simple example

```
function wrapper(a,b)
    c = first_function(a,b)
    d = second_function(c)
    if typeof(d) == Int64
        e = third_function(d)
        f = fourth_function(e)    
        g = fifth_function(f)
        try 
            h = sixth_function(g)
        catch
            i = "this has failed"
        end
        i = seventh_function(h)
    else i = "this has failed"
    end

    return i
end
```

There are about 5 different places throughout the list of functions that I want to set up 'if - else' statements or 'try - catch' statements. The 'else' part and the 'catch' part are always evaluating the same things. In this example you can see what I mean by seeing that both the else and the catch statements execute i = "this has failed".

Is there a way that I can just define  i = "this has failed" at the bottom of the function's code and just tell julia to skip to this line for the 'else' or 'catch' parts ? For example I'd like my above to be something like:

```
function wrapper(a,b)
    c = first_function(a,b)
    d = second_function(c)
    if typeof(d) == Int64
        e = third_function(d)
        f = fourth_function(e)    
        g = fifth_function(f)
        try 
            h = sixth_function(g)
        catch
            <skip to line 10>
        end
        i = seventh_function(h)
    else <skip to line 10>
    end

    <line 10> i = "this has failed"
    return i
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got some great *literal* answers answering your *literal* question, but the real question is why do you need to do it like this in the first place? It sounds like a really bad design decision. Essentially you're reinventing the wheel, badly! You're trying to implement a "subroutine" approach as opposed to a "functional" approach; subroutines have all but disappeared decades ago, for good reason. The fact that your question essentially boils down to "GOTO for Julia" [should be a really big red flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto).

Why not just define another function that handles your "fail code" and just call it? You can even define the fail function *inside* your wrapper function; nested functions are perfectly acceptable in julia. e.g.

```
julia> function outer()
         function inner()
           print("Hello from inner\n");
         end
         print("Hello from outer\n");
         inner();
       end
outer (generic function with 1 method)

julia> outer()
Hello from outer
Hello from inner
```

So in your case you could simply define a nested `handle_failure()` function inside your wrapper function and call it whenever you feel like it and that's all there is to it.

---

PS: Preempting the typical "there are some legit uses for GOTO in modern code" comment: yes; this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@def` macro from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358528/julia-structuring-code-with-many-different-but-related-algorithm-choices). For example:

```
@def i_fail_code begin
  i = "this has failed"
end
```

and then you'd do:

```
function wrapper(a,b)
    c = first_function(a,b)
    d = second_function(c)
    if typeof(d) == Int64
        e = third_function(d)
        f = fourth_function(e)    
        g = fifth_function(f)
        try 
            h = sixth_function(g)
        catch
            @i_fail_code
        end
        i = seventh_function(h)
    else @i_fail_code
    end
    return i
end
```

This macro is pretty cool because even though it's essentially just copy/pasting what's in its definition it will even get the line numbers for errors correct (i.e. it will send you to the correct line in the `@def` definition).

Answer (score 2):

Julia has built in `goto` support via macros, which may be the simplest option. So something like:

```
function wrapper(a,b)
    c = first_function(a,b)
    d = second_function(c)
    if typeof(d) == Int64
        e = third_function(d)
        f = fourth_function(e)    
        g = fifth_function(f)
        try 
            h = sixth_function(g)
        catch
            @goto fail
        end
        i = seventh_function(h)
    else 
        @goto fail
    end
    return i
    @label fail 
    i = "this has failed"
    return i
end
```

Comment: The [SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/julia-lang/5564/goto-and-label/19761/error-cleanup#t=201610040229210370808) has another example of using the `@goto fail` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that you almost never want to test the type of a variable in Julia -  you should handle that by multiple dispatch instead.